# How do I download Xcode 4.4 without using the App Store?

Tags: xcode

Following an upgrade to Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.3 no longer functions. I need 4.4.

## Download link

I've not been able to get a link for Xcode 4.4, has anyone else found it?

### Reasons for not using the App Store in this case

I don't own a Mac, so I can't copy from one to another.

The Mac where Xcode 4.4 is required is corporate. The upgrade to the OS was volume licensed, performed without the App Store – IT provided the installer to me.

I don't have a corporate credit card (or PayPal) to use with this Mac.  I'll not enter my personal credit card information in an account on a corporate Mac.

I read about "None" being a payment option for free apps, however it's not available on my machine.

Comment: Why not download on your personal machine and just copy the app over ? Edit: also, as a sysadmin I feel I should mention that if you really need this software maybe you should get IT to provide you with the internal officially sanctioned version ;-)

Comment: None _is_ a payment option in the Mac App Store; I personally have used an account with no credit card or PayPal account to download Xcode 4.4. I think you have to sign up via iTunes itself to be able to get the "none" option...

Comment: @Tyr Unfortunately, I can't download and copy from my personal machine as I do not own a Mac.  :-)  IT Mac support is quite limited, there's no internal officially sanctioned XCode at all yet.  OS X 10.8 is the first volume licensing that they've done.  Historically, Macs have been kind of off on their own.  They're just now being integrated into the IT department's control.

Comment: @gtmtg BTDT, it's not an option on my machine.  I read of others that were able to, as well as others that were not.  I've even tried different regions to see if it would show up.  No luck.  How long ago did you do yours?  Perhaps it's a feature that's been removed.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I set mine up quite a while ago, but I found an [Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534) that was updated recently that explains the process...

Comment: I recently used my local branch office's IT support email address to sign into the MAS and purchase ML using my own credit card; I used iTunes to access that account and then change the CC info back to 'None.'  Apple has greatly simplified the process of setting up a no-CC MAS/iTMS account, mostly as a result of this same situation (and many cranky sysadmins like yours truly).  Try signing out and back in in iTunes, then access your account; you should be able to set payment to none, then download any free apps from the MAS.

Comment: Apple still requires a credit card for new accounts. See [Why can’t I select None when I edit my Apple ID payment information?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905) which says "If you're using the store for the first time with an existing Apple ID, you must provide a payment method." Hopefully your workplace has a different option, because it's best to keep personal credit cards and corporate equipment separate.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski - I was just recently (a couple weeks ago) able to get around it with an iPad 3 (and new account), by opening the app store and trying to download a free app.  The signup from the free app download allowed me to select "none" for payment option, and it appears to have stuck.  If you do the regular signup, there isn't a "none" option...

Comment: You would think Apple could make this easier if they wanted too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Now

### Xcode 4.4.1 amongst [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

4.4 was made available 2012-07-26.

4.4.1 was made available 2012-08-07:

- `xcode_4.4.1_6938145.dmg`

Freely available to members of the Safari Developer Program, and to others.

Don't rush to also download the disk image for command line tools. You may find these tools amongst the installation and update options that are integral to Xcode.

---

## Looking ahead

### Apple's software update catalogue

`index-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog` sometimes refers to downloads that are not advertised at [Apple - Support - Downloads](http://support.apple.com/downloads/).

Nothing for Xcode in the [index](http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog) dated 2012-08-09T03:35:35Z … maybe later.

### [Munki approaches to Xcode](https://code.google.com/p/munki/wiki/Xcode)

Nothing there yet for 4.4 or greater but we might find something in due course.

Comment: Since other questions are being closed and pointed to this one, can someone please update these instructions for Xcode 5 & Xcode 6?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry but 4.3 is the last version which you can directly download through developer website.

This might not be the best suggestion but if you really want to get 4.4 without using AppStore then look for a torrent there are many floating around.

And Usually Apple preview builds are quite stable. other valid alternative would be to download XCode 4.5 Developer Preview directly from developer site.

Comment: 4.4 was made available in July, some time before this answer.

Comment: Looks like they're continuing to release Xcode (I just downloaded 4.6.1). Might want to delete this comment...